# Decrypt data in recovery after bootloop

Tags: twrp, encryption, lineageos, fairphone-3

I’ve made a little mistake.

This year, I’ve installed LineageOS for MicroG on my Fairphone3. It provides OTA updates but with the last one, it is said I must follow the official instructions on LineageOS website. It was not a prioritiy, so I didn’t do it. At the begining of the month, I’ve open the web page and read the instructions. There are simple, so i’ve done it.

But, I’ve forgotten that my version was MicroG. I’ve installed the “normal” version (lineage-19.1-20220926). Now, my FP3 is in a bootloop . May be due to the absence of MicroG). I’ve tried to install a newer version of LineageOS for MicroG, without success.

My problems are :

- I would like to retrieve data
- Data directory is encrypted
- I’ve locked my phone with a pattern

I’ve found a solution to try a decrypt with Santoku Linux. The script needs a header and a footer. I have found the header but not the footer.

**Do you know where to find it ?** It seems these files are different accordind to the manufacturer.

Comment: Update, just in case someone has an answer. If not, I'll delete ^^

Comment: No need to delete any good question!